# applicationWillEnterForeground (and other UIApplication Delegate functions) no longer called when StoreKit confirmation Alert is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

On iOS 7.1 the App Delegate receives calls for `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` when the `StoreKit` purchase confirmation Alert is presented to the user when attempting to request payment.

The same behavior is triggered when requesting Microphone Access or Camera Access.

On iOS 8 Beta 5, the delegate calls are no longer triggered in these scenarios, Notifications registered in `UINotification` center for these same events are not received either.

Is this change in behavior expected on iOS 8?  I was unable to find any references to this change in the Pre-Release Developer Library or Developer Forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`applicationWillResignActive` not being called when sending app to background was a bug in iOS 8 betas (1 through 5), but it has been fixed for the final version. I couldn't find mention of it in any changelogs, but it was fixed for me and another developer on Apple's developer forums. I'm assuming same holds for `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

Comment: You are absolutely right that this was fixed in the GM.  We noticed the same thing but I neglected to follow up on this question.  Thanks!